# ADFS 3 WAP Pre-auth error 511 - 364

Tags: adfs

Very simple setup 2 adfs BE Servers and one proxy. Application name https://adfsapps.abc.local/ADFSApp1/ (basic Claims aware App). STS url is STS2.abc.local.
If Application is published as Pass-Thru it works fine But if Pre-Authentication is used then getting errors 511 which says -

The incoming sign-in request is not allowed due to an invalid Federation Service configuration.

Request url: 
 /adfs/ls?version=1.0&action=signin&realm=urn'%'3AAppProxy'%'3Acom&appRealm=39015c2f-5b7e-e511-80be-00155d1b2104&returnUrl=https'%'3A'%'2F'%'2Fadfsapps.abc.local'%'2FADFSApp1'%'2F&client-request-id=356DDEB4-1336-0000-1EE6-6D353613D101

User Action:
 Examine the Federation Service configuration and take the following actions: 
  Verify that the sign-in request has all the required parameters and is formatted correctly. 
  Verify that a web application proxy relying party trust exists, is enabled, and has identifiers which match the sign-in request parameters. 
  Verify that the target relying party trust object exists, is published through the web application proxy, and has identifiers which match the sign-in request parameters.

AND Error 364 -
Encountered error during federation passive request.

Additional Data 
Protocol Name: 
Relying Party: 
Exception details: 
Microsoft.IdentityServer.Web.InvalidRequestException: MSIS7009: The request was malformed or not valid. Contact your administrator for details.
   at Microsoft.IdentityServer.Web.Protocols.MSISHttp.MSISHttpProtocolHandler.ValidateSignInContext(MSISHttpSignInRequestContext msisContext, WrappedHttpListenerRequest request)
   at Microsoft.IdentityServer.Web.Protocols.MSISHttp.MSISHttpProtocolHandler.CreateProtocolContext(WrappedHttpListenerRequest request)
   at Microsoft.IdentityServer.Web.PassiveProtocolListener.GetProtocolHandler(WrappedHttpListenerRequest request, ProtocolContext& protocolContext, PassiveProtocolHandler& protocolHandler)
   at Microsoft.IdentityServer.Web.PassiveProtocolListener.OnGetContext(WrappedHttpListenerContext context)

The events get generated at the BE Servers.
Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: No Comments so far ?!